# Do I have a case to challenge a private medical invoice that wasn't covered by insurance?

Tags: contract-law, insurance, medical, breach-of-contract, health-insurance

I had private medical insurance as part of my employer, I rang up in October for an appointment and one was "authorised" for January.

I then left my job in December and still attended in January.  (I wrongly thought I'd be charged if I didn't attend and that as it was authorised this was fine...)

However, as I left my employer my insurance was void and I've been hit with a £500 hospital bill for a 15 minute appointment.

When I attended the appointment I signed a form that basically said if my insurance doesn't cover the cost I will have to.

My question though centres around signing a "blank cheque" - are they legally able to chase me for whatever figure they choose??

When I signed the form I had no idea how much the costs would be. Surely they have a role to inform me before the event?   I kept thinking to myself if I had a MRI done I would be bankrupt.

Do I have a case to fight this in some way?

I took my insurance to the ombudsman but as this took 15 months to gain a response, I've also been hit with the "interest" for this period.

Any advice would really help..

---

Update:
The ombudsman advised that the insurance company didn't have to pay out as within their terms it said if I leave the policy is void.

Comment: I am mindful that you are new to Law SE (welcome, BTW). Going forward, if you update your question after an answer has been posted, please notify the author of that answer. Many of us post our answer and don't usually keep track of whether an OP edits the question thereafter unless the OP notifies us. That would have obviated much of the vexation by another user in this post. Your update evidently went unnoticed by him as well, since he brought it to my attention just now. Regardless, hope your matter gets solved one way or the other.

Comment: Sure, i'll tag the author in future, i wasn't sure the best way to update this.

Answer (score -1):

**Prior to OP's update of the question ...**

> Do I have a case to fight this in some way?

Without knowing whether UK legislation has a superseding provision in this regard, you seemingly have a meritorious position from the standpoint of contract law.

Your employment provided medical insurance as a benefit, [I assume] you accrued that benefit, and sought to use it while you were still employed there. To the extent that the delay in enforcing that benefit is not attributable to you (but to others such as the employer, the insurer, or the physician), the bills resulting strictly from that appointment are to be covered by whoever would be responsible therefor had the appointment occurred shortly after you requested it.

A contrary conclusion would imply that an employee's entitlement to accrued benefits is ultimately contingent on someone else's acts or omissions. That implication would generally encourage negligence --or perhaps deliberate obstruction-- in the performance of contracts.

The accrual & entitlement argument would fail if this sort of contingency were reasonably outlined in your contract(s) with the employer, insurer, or service provider. That being said, the form you were asked to sign during the appointment does not appear to inform you of that contingency.

You did not specify what the ombudsman responded. That information could shed more light on the legal merits of your position.

**Upon OP's update/supplement of information ...**

> Do I have a case to fight this in some way?

No. The terms of the policy as outlined by the ombudsman are decisive (this is in line with [one of my comments](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/46953/do-i-have-a-case-to-challenge-a-private-medical-invoice-that-wasnt-covered-by-i/46957?noredirect=1#comment90797_46957)). I'm assuming that the ombudsman reading of the policy is accurate.

Moreover, the form you signed at the appointment reinforces the hospital's position that you are responsible for the expenses ensuing from the appointment. Signing that form placed on you the burden of first ascertaining an estimate of the expenses, it being the case that you knew --or should have known-- that you were no longer covered by policy.

These two last reasons --whether taken together or separately-- are likely to outweigh the merits of arguing that your appointment was delayed by having it scheduled for months later (see the initial version of this answer).

Proving that the bill is egregiously high in comparison with similar scenarios might be the only argument that could lead to a reduction of the bill, although this seems to be a stretch. Other than that, there is nothing you can do to reasonably dispute the bill(s) and surcharges.

That being said, I am keeping the initial version of my answer [that is, from prior to your update] because that rationale will guide others on how to assess akin scenarios where the issue *is not* determined by the terms of the policy or contract. Also, this showcases how leaving out one piece of crucial information can lead to the opposite conclusion.

Comment: I don't think that medical insurance is an _accrued_ benefit. Accrued benefits are benefits that accrue (add up) over the duration of employment, such as Paid Time Off. Not that it really matters. You're bunching up the employer and the insurer here, but it appears that the case would be against the insurer. It only matters _if and when_ he was insured, not _why_.

Comment: @MSalters Whether accrued or earned, the OP was entitled to a benefit as part of a compensation package. I agree that generally speaking the OP might have to go after the insurer, but it is unclear to me whether by "authorised" the OP meant another entity or whether the employer had a role in canceling the coverage for the delayed appointment.

Comment: I'd think that insurance ends when the employment ends.  Canceling the policy cancels the authorization.  I don't knows uk law but it seems absurd that this answer would be correct.

Comment: @Andy That sort of retroactive cancellation of delayed coverage seems impermissible unless coverage was procured fraudulently. There is no indication of fraud in the scenario the OP describes. There is merely a delay --presumably by some third party-- on enforcing a benefit to which the OP was already entitled insofar as he/she was still employed there. Your premise that "canceling the policy cancels the authorization" would encourage certain obligors to delay matters with hope that in the meantime their obligations will extinguish circumstantially.

Comment: The issue is that there is no coverage at the time the procedure takes place.   The approval almost certainly is valid only if the policy is still in affect when the service is actually performed.  It's not "we'll pay for x service on y date no matter what, " it's "we'll pay for x service on y date provided your policy is still effective on y date."  Prior approvals are done for things to ensure they are actually medically neccessary in the eyes of the insurance company, and that's it.

Comment: @Andy "*we'll pay for x service on y date provided your policy is still effective on y date.*". That is something for the OP to verify from the contract and/or the insurance policy. Other than that, your rationale eludes my point about delaying the benefits as a method --or in the attempt-- to basically deny them.

Comment: You seem to have made up something about delaying benefits; that's not how health insurance works.  You're covered on the policy or you're not.  Your answer mentions accruing health insurance.  You can't.  Your employer will allow you to join their policy, sometimes after a probationary period, and then you're covered.  When you leave, your insurance is canceled.  Its really that simple, but your answer makes up a bunch of nonsense to try and explain how the insurance might still have to pay.

Comment: @Andy If the issue of delaying benefits were "a bunch of nonsense", you would have no problem addressing it. But you keep eluding this with "*that's not how health insurance works*". [*Travelers Ins. Co. v. Savio*, 706 P.2d 1258, 1273 (1985)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19851964706p2d125811935) identifies insurers' motivation for delaying payments of claims, the resulting inequity "*becom[ing] particularly apparent in the area of disability insurance*". This is akin to the OP's matter except that, instead of delaying payment, here the third party preemptively delayed the benefit itself.

Comment: There's no benefit to delay; the appointment happened **while he was not insured**.      So you're making up some BS issue which has nothing to do with the question.  That's why I'm not discussing it.  Its beyond me how you cannot understand such a simple point.

Comment: @Andy Enforcement of the benefit was requested *and* authorized while the OP was insured. Your remark that "*There's no benefit to delay*" suggests that you haven't yet noticed OP's mention that appointment was scheduled for *months later*. Such scheduling is tantamount to delaying the benefit. Your "logic" implies that it is permissible for a party to try getting away with his contract obligations by delaying them. However, that contravenes contract law, whence you opted to keep avoiding the point and get all heated up. Glad you now desist from going in circles. Let's see if you truly do so.

Comment: That is **not** how medical insurance prior authorizations works. The authorization is **only** good if, on the date of service, your policy is still effective.  It was not for the OP.  The prior authorization is **NOT** a promise to pay for the visit no matter what.  It does **not** reflect policy coverage.

Comment: Let me put this another way; there are **no insurance** products for ANYTHING which pay for events which occur WHILE YOU ARE NOT INSURED.  Auto insurance only covers accidents which occur WHILE YOUR POLICY IS EFFECTIVE, life insurance only pays if the insured dies WHILE THE POLICY IS EFFECTIVE, medical insurance only pays for services **PERFORMED** WHILE THE POLICY IS EFFECTIVE.  When the appointment is scheduled makes zero difference.

Comment: @Andy "*When the appointment is scheduled makes zero difference*". Again: It matters because the delay of the appointment increases the likelihood of deprivation of benefits to which the OP was entitled by contract.

Comment: No, it makes zero difference.  The only dates that matter are the beginning and ending date of the policy coverage, and the **date of service**.  You do not get coverage if your policy is not in effect **on the date of service**.  Period, end of story, there's no such thing in this situation as delaying of benefits.  There is absolutely, 100%, no chance that the procedure will be covered if performed while the policy is not in effect.  The benefit the insurance provides is that they **might** cover the payment of services done **while the policy is effective**.

Comment: Insurances can also require prior authorization for medications, and they will typically last a number of months, possibly up to a year.  But again, they will only pay for refills to a covered medication **while the policy is active**.

Comment: @Andy Then, according to your misconception that scheduling far in advance "makes zero difference", an employee's benefit appointment may be *scheduled for January 2065* (by which time the employee will have retired or work elsewhere) and thus he --not the insurer-- will have to cover the expenses because he will no longer be employed there (ergo, policy will no longer be effective) on the date of the appointment. And all employers & insurers are allowed to and will adopt the tactic of *scheduling far in advance* now that "*that is how it works*".

Comment: It is the insured which makes the appointment, not the employer, not the insurer.  The benefit here is **not** the appointment or the service.  The benefit is the __insurance itself__, which **might** cover payment for the service, and the insurance contract does stipulate they won't pay for anything which occurs outside the effective dates of the policy.  You do realize that the insurance contract also dictates which drugs will be covered or not, which drugs will be covered in specific situations, and whether or not you need to be referred to a specialist or not for the insurance to cover it.

Comment: @Andy Phrases such as "*It is the insured which makes the appointment, not the employer, not the insurer*" and "*The benefit here is not the appointment or the service*" indicate you are here just for the sake of vexation. The OP requested the appointment, but the counterparty is the one who determined its date. Additionally, you keep trying to expand the debate to policy coverage of drugs and items that are beyond the scope of the OP's question. At this point the OP surely has identified what to do and who keeps coming up with useless trivialities. I got no time for you. Good bye.

Comment: The doctors office and the OP determined the date, the employer and insurer were not involved.  The insurer only said they'd pay (either part or all) for the visit, but of course that authorization is only valid if the insurance remains valid.  I'm not trying to expand anything; pre-auths work the same way for medication that they do appointments, that's what I'm trying to get through your thick skull.  Sorry, but my wife spent 15 years only working on pre-auths at her work place, I know how they work, you clearly don't.

Comment: Oh, by the way, the OP updated his question, and he was told the exact same thing I've been saying.  Your answer is 100% without a doubt **WRONG**.

Comment: @Andy Don't expect an answer to fill the gaps on information OPs either do not provide or added belatedly. Prior to posting my answer, neither the contents of ombudsman's response nor the terms of policy were reflected in the OP's question. I pointed that out at the end of my answer and in a [previous comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/46953/do-i-have-a-case-to-challenge-a-private-medical-invoice-that-wasnt-covered-by-i/46957?noredirect=1#comment90797_46957) to you, accordingly. With that crucial information missing, the only available argument was to be premised on contract law.

Comment: Yet i knew your answer was wrong before that update because i know your take in the delayed benefits was nonsense, because that's just not how insurance works, ever. No insurance will pay for something that happens when a policy is not valid, but you made up this delayed benefits reasoning to say the op could have a valid legal claim, when he never did.

Comment: If it helps - I didn't have cover at the time of my appointment. I accept this.  However my question around the law is around this blank cheque aspect. I didn't sign a document that allows them to charge me whatever they want without letting me the costs upfront.

Comment: @Chris You might prevail on the "blank cheque" issue if you prove that the amount unjustifiably exceeds what is billed in situations which are *materially* similar (see 2nd-to-last paragraph in the answer). Other than that, your decision to sign the form --without inquiring any further-- released the hospital from having to let you know in advance a billing estimate. That is why I suggested (prior to the post being updated) considering a *contract law* argument.

Comment: @Andy "*i knew your answer was wrong before that update*". Good for you. The thing is that the ombudsman's response is of the sort "*within their terms it said [...]*" (referring to the terms of the *contract*, thus being premised on **contract law**), unlike "*[my wife spent there 15 years](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/46953/do-i-have-a-case-to-challenge-a-private-medical-invoice-that-wasnt-covered-by-i/46957?noredirect=1#comment91307_46957) and that's how health insurance works*".

Comment: You're being purposefully obtuse.  I have been saying all along that the policy (e.g, the contract) states that they will not cover anything that has been authorized but occurs after the termination of the policy, because that is the policy.  **That's how the insurance industry works** means that **all** health insurers cancel authorizations when the policy ends, because the entire prior authorization system is invented by the insurers and coded into their policies to control their costs.  My wife's experience then is reading and understanding these contracts, which they never cover...

Comment: ... anything after the policy is canceled.  My entire objection to your answer[1] all along was this made up belief that accrued benefits somehow comes into play and thus the OP might have some sort of case.  [1] https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/46957/1

Comment: @Andy "*I have been saying all along that the policy (e.g, the contract) states that [...]*". Again, good for you. The rest of us are not prescient, which is why we did not know the terms of OP's contract beforehand. The OP later clarified it for us the non-prescient. And, again, the ombudsman's response to the OP was not like "*That's how the insurance industry works [...]. My wife's experience [...]*". Instead, the ombudsman aptly decided to assess the terms of the OP's contract/policy, since a contract may supersede (i.e., lawfully) in many ways how "all health insurers" ordinarily operate.

Comment: You continue to be purposefully obtuse; my assertion is/was that in this case all health insurance policies will contain the same clauses.  All of them define a system of prior authorizations, because all of them are trying to control their costs.  Its a defacto industry standard.  Its similar to how auto insurance will explicitly not cover custom modifications to a car without the insured buying a separate rider (if they even offer that as an option).  its an extremely safe assumption to make, yet you denied that it was even a possibility.  Next time go educate yourself when you get pushback.

Comment: @Andy "*my assertion is/was that in this case all health insurance policies will contain the same clauses*" Thanks for sharing your prediction. I would nonetheless place more reliance on the ombudsman's reflection of the OP's contract, since the *specific* contract that the ombudsman assessed determines these parties' rights and duties, regardless of your predictions and of insurers' common practices. The latter gain relevance only when a contract leaves an issue undefined. Contract law exists precisely because it is valid and realistic for parties to agree to depart from *de facto* standards.

Comment: "The latter gain relevance only when a contract leaves an issue undefined. "  The standard practice here is to include a clause in the insurance contract which terminates any prior authorization granted when the policy is ended. And they all do; it's not a prediction, it's knowledge of the industry gained from someone with more than 20 years of reading and understanding 100s of policies, from both the insurer and health care provider side.  You assert that there might be a policy out there that doesn't, then the burden of proof is on you.

Comment: @Andy You are the one who would need (and fail) to persuade that the existence of a standard precludes two parties from ever entering a contract that departs from that standard. Suppose that red paint is cheaper than blue, so your rationale translates to this: "*For 15~20 years my wife has seen only red cars, so my assertion is that a car maker will never ever **ever** enter a contract to sell a blue car because red is cheaper than blue and car makers try to control their costs; it's a standard*". You ignore that crucial clauses of contracts can be and *oftentimes are* customized.

Comment: Group health care polices and the paint color of a car are in no way analogous.  Often there is no customization of group heath policies because the employer not the employee decide on the plan. The employees choice is typically sign up for it or don't.  The clause you think that might exist is that an insurance contract would pay for a normally covered event that occurs during a time the policy is no longer effective, some kind of perpetual coverage.  So no you have the burden of proof here, as your claim is absurd and unreasonable.